# How to use a cell value as part of a range using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How can you use a cell value to populate a range in VBA?

In this example I want to copy a selection and paste it into a row based on the value of cell L2 with the row number being the same as the L2 value.

The last line of code i understand is incorrect, but can't figure out a suitable solution that would select B100:K100 for example.

```
Set Rng1 = Range("L2").Value
Range("B2:K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B" & Range(Rng1) : "K" & Range(Rng1).Select
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you want row of L2 cell, use as follow:

```
Range("B" & Rng1.Row & ":K" & Rng1.Row).Select
```

If you want value of L2 cell, use as follow:

```
Range("B" & Rng1 & ":K" & Rng1).Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly cleaner version of DragonSamu's response:

```
Dim IntRow As Integer
IntRow = Range("L2").Value
Range("B2:K2").Copy
Range("B" & IntRow & ":K" & IntRow).Paste
```

VBA best practices avoid using `.select` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Building on DragonSamu & Dr. Treys response:

```
Dim IntRow As Integer
IntRow = Range("L2").Value
Range("B2:K2").Copy Destination:=Cells(IntRow, 2)
```

Cells references a single cell, but will paste the whole range as required.
As long as you're not using paste special you can copy and paste in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
Dim IntRow As Integer
IntRow = Range("L2").Value
Range("B2:K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B" & IntRow & ":K" & IntRow).Select
```

Instead of defining a range by collecting the value of a cell and then applying it as the row number for the selection, you simply define IntRow as Integer store your row value in IntRow and use it in the range select.